# Replication of data across the cluster in Cassandra database

Tags: hadoop, nosql, cassandra, bigdata

According to DataStax Each node communicates with each other through the Gossip protocol, which exchanges information across the cluster...

I just wanted to know:

is it really possible to replicate 100gb data in 1 sec across the cluster????????

if it is..then how it's possible..using what kind of technique...can you elaborate??

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question? What exactly is your use case?

Comment: is it really possible to replicate 100gb data in 1 sec across the cluster????????

Comment: if it is..then how it's possible..using what kind of technique??

Comment: Because the cluster's capabilities grow linearly with the amount of machines, a large enough cluster can simply stream the information required. Since each machine is only takes care of a portion of the total data, they can work together to achieve a faster data transfer rate

Comment: "Since each machine is only takes care of a portion of the total data"

Comment: can u please clarify above point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gossip protocol is just to share state information around the cluster. This is how Cassandra nodes discover new ones and detect if nodes are unavailable.

Data, however, is not transferred using gossip. Messages are sent directly to replicas during inserts and bulk streaming is done during bootstrap/decommission/repair.